# lift of the boundary of the projection of a convex body

Tags: general-topology, convex-analysis, convex-geometry

Let $M\subset\mathbb{R}^3$ be a (compact) convex body and denote $\pi:(x, y, z)\to(x,y)$ the projection to the $xy$-plane. The image $\pi(M)$ is a convex shape on $\mathbb{R}^2$, and has a boundary $B=\partial\pi(M)$. Is it true that:

There is a continuous curve $C\subset \pi^{-1}(B)\cap M$ such that the projection $\pi |_C: C\to B$ is a homeomorphism?

I have a feeling that this is the case, but couldn't prove it, or couldn't find any online  statements. Could anybody prove or disprove? I tried to construct counter-examples but either did not find any one.

Comment: I'm assuming you want $M$ compact and $C \subset M$?

Comment: @BrianMoehring A convex body is a compact convex set with non-empty interior.

Comment: @BrianMoehring: thanks for the clarification. I updated the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a counterexample.  Let $C_1 = \{ (x,\sqrt{1-x^2},1) \, : \, -1 \le x \le 1 \}$ and let $C_2 = \{(x,-\sqrt{1-x^2},0) \, : \, -1 \le x \le 1\}$. Let $M$ be the convex hull of $C_1 \cup C_2$.  Then $\pi(M)$ is the unit disk and $B$ is the unit circle.  If a point $(x,y) \in B$ has $y > 0$, then the only pre-image lies in $C_1$, and if $y < 0$, then the only pre-image lies in $C_2$.  Therefore, there cannot be a curve $C$ in $M$ such that $\pi$ restricted to $C$ is a homeomorphism onto $B$.

Comment: Thanks. Can we still say anything about this? Like: There is always a continuous curve $C\subset M$ such that $\pi(C)=B$? In your example we can still connect the upper and down curves by two vertical segments, though the projection is not a homeomorphism.

Comment: I think that is true, although I don't see a nice proof right away.